# HttpUrlConnection POST request not working....How to solve this?

Tags: android

HttpUrlConnection POST request not working. Tell me if there is any other way to make POST request in android.Tell me if there is any other way to make POST request in android.Tell me if there is any other way to make POST request in android.

```
 public final String apiCall(String pUrl) {
    if( ! isInternetAvailable() )
        return "NO_INTERNET";

    try {
        URL lUrl = new URL(pUrl.replace(" ", "%20"));
        Log.i("url", String.valueOf(lUrl));

       String url = pUrl;

        Log.i("dom", url.substring(0, (url.indexOf('?') - 1)));
        Log.i("para", url.substring((url.indexOf('?') + 1), url.length()) );

        URL obj = new URL(url.substring(0,(url.indexOf('?')-1)));
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "GYUserAgentAndroid");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        String urlParameters = url.substring((url.indexOf('?')+1), url.length());
        Log.i("urlParameters", urlParameters.toString());

        // Send post request
        con.setDoInput(true); // true if we want to read server's response
        con.setDoOutput(true); // false indicates this is a GET request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();


        Log.i("res",response.toString());
        return response.toString();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("secondEx",e.toString());
        return "ERROR";
    }

}
```

Comment: I advice you to use  Retrofit -It is a type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java.

here  you can study this 

  http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
InputStream inputStream; 
HttpURLConnection urlConnection; 
byte[] outputBytes;

public class WebServiceAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(Url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            outputBytes = query.getBytes("UTF-8");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            urlConnection.connect();

            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(outputBytes);
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            ResponseData = convertStreamToString(inputStream);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return ResponseData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);


    }

    public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append((line + "\n"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Pass your parameters in json string format like this

```
JSONObject() params = new JSONObject();
params.put("key","your parameter");
params.put("key","your parameter");

query=params.toString();
```

Check [this](https://www.studytutorial.in/android-httpurlconnection-post-and-get-request-tutorial) link for reference

Comment: outputBytes ?      query?

Comment: query is the parameters which you send to the post api. It is in json String format

Comment: is there necessary to create JSONObject , bcoz I've directly assigned parameters string to string variable like this String urlParameters = url.substring((url.indexOf('?')+1), url.length()); and .urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8");

Comment: Well it depends on your requirement..If it requires paramenters in json format then you have to use it otherwise you can send that too..Try it

Answer (score 0):

Another way to perform requests is [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

You can find a good tutorial [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit)