# How to solve java.net.UnknownHostException from HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, url, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am trying to implement an SMS phone number verification program on a remote server. The method below is called by a Servlet, I am trying to connect to the SMS service provider so that they can send an SMS to the specified phone number:

```
public static int sendPhoneNumberVerication(User user) throws SQLException, IOException, IllegalArgumentException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    String email = user.getEmail();
    String phoneNumber = user.getPhoneNumber();
    String verificationCode = getVerificationCode(email);
    String message = getPhoneVerificationMessage(user, verificationCode);
    //The sending SMS part
    String address = "https://www.bulksmsnigeria.com/api/v1/sms/create?api_token=fHTGT6PiRxIE1ZrMvOTDcsu0cM5yiQKz2EnWAXxQqkMt6UlAUHwHGIBFxQW4&from=Matonia&to=" + phoneNumber + "&body=" + message;
    URL url = new URL(address);
    //URL url = new URL("https", "www.bulksmsnigeria.com", 80, "/api/v1/sms/create?api_token=fHTGT6PiRxIE1ZrMvOTDcsu0cM5yiQKz2EnWAXxQqkMt6UlAUHwHGIBFxQW4&from=Matonia&to=" + phoneNumber + "&body=" + message);
    HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    try(InputStream inputStream = urlConn.getInputStream())//<- Exception is throw here
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(bytes);
        String content = new String(bytes);
        //Get the HTTP response status code
        int statusCode = urlConn.getResponseCode();
        return statusCode;
    }
}
```

When the servlet is executed, I get the following exception:

```
 java.net.UnknownHostException: www.
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:649)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1103)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2645)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2574)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1768)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at com.peer2peer.users.UserDAO.sendPhoneNumberVerication(UserDAO.java:406)
at com.peer2peer.users.UpdateProfileServlet.sendPhoneValidation(UpdateProfileServlet.java:261)
at com.peer2peer.users.UpdateProfileServlet.processRequest(UpdateProfileServlet.java:52)
at com.peer2peer.users.UpdateProfileServlet.doGet(UpdateProfileServlet.java:333)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at ...
```

When I tried using the following code to instantiate URL:

```
URL url = new URL("https", "www.bulksmsnigeria.com", 80, "/api/v1/sms/create?api_token=fHTGT6PiRxIE1ZrMvOTDcsu0cM5yiQKz2EnWAXxQqkMt6UlAUHwHGIBFxQW4&from=Matonia&to=" + phoneNumber + "&body=" + message);
```

I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?`

If I change the `https` to `http`, I get `301` as status code.
However if I run the URL address on the web browser I get this: 
[image]

...and I also received the expected SMS message!

I have also checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469589/httpurlconnection-post-request-not-working-how-to-solve-this), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484275/java-net-unknownhostexception-invalid-hostname-for-server-local), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992586/java-httpurlconnection-java-net-unknownhostexception) and I don't seem to get anything from those posts.
I don't know what I am doing wrong here.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

That's because https does not use port 80. It uses port 443 instead, try the following:

```
URL url = new URL("https", "www.bulksmsnigeria.com", 443, 
    "/api/v1/sms/create?api_token=fHTGT6PiRxIE1ZrMvOTDcsu0cM5yiQKz2EnWAXxQqkMt6UlAUHwHGIBFxQW4&from=Matonia&to=" + phoneNumber + "&body=" + message;
```

Comment: I am still getting `java.net.UnknownHostException: www.`

Comment: Are you sure the server is connected to internet? Can you try with any other url (e.g. `https://www.google.com`)?

Comment: The server I am running the code is a remote server, so I am sure it is connected to the internet. However, I've used that code with another host before (although it wasn't HTTPS) and it worked.

Comment: Could you post the code with actual value of message and phone number so that I can run it as is? So far, I haven't been able to re-produce the bug.

Comment: You can use any message and phone number of your choice @Darshan Mehta, please see if you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you try `ping www.bulksmsnigeria.com` from command line of your server and see if you get replies back? Looks like proxy is not configured in your server.

Comment: I did, I got 4 replies from 173.214.186.111. I even tried using the given IP address on the code and I got the same result.

Answer (score -1):

The HTTP plaintext version of your site is issuing an invalid redirect to `www.`. When you used HTTPS it fails earlier because you're connecting to the wrong port for HTTPS.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, please can you elaborate?

Comment: The exception message is perfectly clear. What part of `java.net.UnknownHostException: www.` didn't you understand?

Comment: @EJP Unless the posted code does not match the code runned, the URL contains a full address, nut just `www`.

Comment: But I did not send it to "www." I used the address that you are seeing.

Comment: @M.leRutte I agree, or unless the posted error message doesn't match the real one. Only the OP can clarify this, and also which of his three questions he wants answered.

Comment: @Jevison7x So this isn't the real error message?

Comment: The error message is real, if you want to see it for yourself I can give you the address of the website to check it out.

Comment: Why would I post a different error message?